# single word to represent the phrase "being available/helpful 24/7" in a team

Tags: single-word-requests

I was just wondering if there was a single word to represent the phrase "something that is available/accessible all the time". The context for this is to thanks all the members of a team who helped to accomplish something and they were available 24/7 for the last few weeks.

Comment: "on-call" perhaps? PS: you might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This concept is common in the IT world.

You could say the team was **highly available**. They had **zero downtime**. They offered **five-nines support**.

> **High availability** is a characteristic of a system, which aims to ensure an agreed level of operational performance, usually uptime, for a higher than normal period.
>   [...] Generally, the term downtime is used to refer to periods when a system is unavailable.
>   - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability)

To be available **“five nines"** [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability#Percentage_calculation) to be available 
 99.999%  of the time, i.e. unavailable 5.26 minutes per year.

You could use terminology regarding **SLA**s.

> **Service-level agreements** can contain numerous service-performance metrics with corresponding service-level objectives. A common case in IT-service management is a call center or service desk. Metrics commonly agreed to in these cases include:      [...]
>
> - TAT (Turn-Around Time): Time taken to complete a certain task.
> - MTTR (Mean Time To Recover): Time taken to recover after an outage of service.
>     [...]
>
> - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement)